# Delphi: Free TSynEdit replacement

Tags: delphi, syntax-highlighting, delphi-2010

What's the best free replacement for TSynEdit? As I can see, it is developed very slow. Want to find some replacement for it. Or, may be, the version from another maintainer.

Need Delphi 2010 compatibility.

Comment: If there is something better, I doubt it will be free. It's like asking for a better free Treeview than VST

Comment: What do you mean "developed very slow"? You only use components that are changing rapidly and gaining new features? What exactly is missing from TButton that it should change? Or from TSynEdit that it should change?  Seriously. LOLz.

Comment: Warren, I don't like to say it, but in that specific case it is justifiable point. SynEdit internals are really huge mess, there are dozens of tricks with the comment which say *following code doesn't make much sense for me but if I change it - it doesn't work*.
Also it is missing some now-standard features (like code folding)
I must however admit it works pretty good at all.

Comment: Show me one major component over which this isn't said. VST gets grief about its node structure and allocation, Indy over the complexity of the mime classes etc etc

Comment: Marco, have a look at DevExpress sources if you can :)

Comment: All the above points are good points.  A balanced and thoughtful question on the subject might be "Is there a component that is as powerful as SynEdit, but which is more cleanly implemented internally", as long as you can specify what is thought to be poorly implemented in SynEdit. Personally I think anybody who thinks SynEdit is poorly implemented but hasn't implemented their own editor from the ground up, is probably talking about something they know too little about to say.

Comment: Why Gutter doesn't show line numbers on TSynEdit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SynEdit works fine under D2010.  There's one notable bug involving the Enter key not working under certain conditions.  A patch for it can be found about halfway down the page on [this thread](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=29485).  Search for `// GB: BUG FIXED`

Aside from that, it should work.  Are you having some specific issues with it?

Comment: I use it all the time, and SynEdit's UniSynEdit version is great.

Comment: Why there is no final version then? The developing of this component seem to be stopped. And if you stumble across some bug - there is none you can cry for help to ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can try out Scintilla. As of version 2.x it supports "virtual space" (most important feature for me - after syntax highlighting) and has more features like CodeFolding, Annotations http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#Annotations, MultipleSelections, and many more.
AFAIK there is no wrapper for Delphi that is up-to-date and works with Unicode/D2009+.
I've created a project at http://code.google.com/p/dscintilla/ which should be in 'beta stage' in a week (or so).

Comment: That sounds nice.  Can it do SyncEdit?

Comment: Yes, it should support that feature. You can add for example 10 carets and edit code in 10 different places at a same time.

Comment: Krystian, now you need to port your excellent SynWeb to Scintilla, as we discussed :)

Comment: I'll wait till the Delphi port :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have never used SynEdit myself, but have always believed it to be the best free open-source advanced editor component for Delphi. Because it is open-source, you can yourself alter it to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, but it will take too much time.

Comment: Yes, with Open Source, you can change it yourself, but you obviously haven't seen the source code for TSynEdit.  It's a mess.